# Загрузка других Dataset

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, tensorflow

Всем привет, я использую библиотеку keras и набор данных mnist для загрузки тренировочных данных:

```
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
```

Но они мне нравятся из за своей некорректности. Каким образом можно загрузить новый data set(Набор рукописных цифр от 0 до 10)?

Comment: скорее всего ответ будет зависеть от того в каком виде сохранен датасет, который вы хотите загрузить...

Comment: архив с расширением .gz

Comment: а что в архиве? Это ваш собственный датасет или стандартный MNIST?

Comment: Стандартный mnist, я хочу его поменять

Comment: можете уточнить суть вопроса? поменять на что? вы хотите загрузить собственный набор изображений? в виде набора картинок или как-то по-другому?

Comment: Я хочу получить новый набор данных

Comment: Но только что бы он был в том формате как и mnist.load_data()

Comment: посмотрите как реализован `mnist.load_data()` и сделайте по его подобию..